# Removing column in a list<T> in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list I want to remove the column RiskRegisterEntryId and RiskRegisterTypeId how can I to do that..?

```
 SeriesNumber       RiskRegisterEntryId RiskRegisterTypeId  RiskRegisterType
 RCMSRA19111300001      1               1                   Site Risk Audit
 RCMSRA19111300002      2               1                   Site Risk Audit
 RCMSRA19111300003      3               1                   Site Risk Audit
 RCMSRA19111300004      4               1                   Site Risk Audit
 RCMSRA20111300016      16              1                   Site Risk Audit
```

Comment: What do you mean by `remove the column`?

Comment: You have list of what?

Comment: it depends on the type `T`, if you have another type `T2` having less properties than `T`, use that `T2`. Or you may want to use some anonymous type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just create a new list of an anonymous type without those columns:

```
var newList = myList.Select(l => new {
     l.SeriesNumber , l.RiskRegisterType
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: I think `newList` is called a `List<>` only if we append some `ToList()` on the query. BTW, you missed the last `);`

Comment: @KingKing fixed both.

Answer (score 2):

```
List.Select(x => new { x.SeriesNumber, x.RiskRegisterType});
```

This will create a list with an anonymous type containing only those two fields.

Comment: did you mean `new{ x.SeriesNumber, x.RiskRegisterType}` because there's no overload of `Select` which takes 2 args like that